# Is applying multiple styles to a CSS class good practice?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to CSS and have run into an issue where `text-align: right;` does not work in a chrome browser, however `text-align: -webkit-right;` works just fine when applied to a `<div>` element.
To ensure that this works across multiple browsers, I've implemented the CSS in the following way, where the div class name is `reload`:

```
.reload {   
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    text-align: -webkit-right;
    text-align: -moz-right;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

My question is whether or not this is an acceptable practice in specifying multiple styles for an element?

I have noticed that the various browsers strikethrough the styling that they aren't using, for example in chrome the `-moz-right` styling is stricken through.

Comment: *text-align: right; does not work in a chrome browser* --> what version are you using? I don't think there is any existing version of Chrome that doesn't support text-align:right

Comment: ^ there is 0 version of chrome where text-align: right will not work: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_text-align

Comment: The version of chrome is Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit); hence the confusion as to why just text-align: right doesn't work, but the -webkit version does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to writing CSS is valid.

Some things to consider though: Will you use the class in multiple places? If so, will those same styles be suitable for other places where it is used?

If you do plan on using the class multiple times, then consider how reusable it is. For example, you could further break down the class like:

```
.right {
    text-align: right;
    text-align: -webkit-right;
    text-align: -moz-right;
}

.mb {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.w-100 {   
    width: 100%;
}
```

The class names I have used are examples - you can name them whatever you find appropriate/memorable.

For 100% width, you could have `.w100`, `.w-100`, `.fw`, `.full-width`, `.width-full`, etc.